# How do I create arrays / average

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
    int n,i,a[n];
    float sr,zb = 0;
    printf("How many elements?:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("Unesite %d. element niza:\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        zb = zb + a[i];
    }   
    sr = zb / n;
    printf("Average is %.2f \n",sr);    
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I don't know where did I made a mistake? Why is my program not responding.

Comment: `a[n];` - What is `n` when you declare this array?

Comment: Put `int a[n];` _after_ `scanf`. If you put it before, `n` has not yet been initialized

Comment: what is n in a[n] ? declare & initialize  n before this statement